# Issue in returning data retrieved from DB queries called in the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, q

I making multiple mongoDB queries in loop. and want to send the all results as one data array.But when I simple use the return for send the data it simply return undefined  and do not wait for results of all DB request. I also tried to use q.moulde but same issue.

Code:

```
var getPrayerInCat = function(data){
    var result ;
    var finalData = [];
    if(data.length >0){
             data.forEach(function(data2){
                 var id= data2.id;
                 Prayer.find({prayerCat:id},function(err,prayer){
                     var deferred = Q.defer()
                     if (err) { // ...
                         console.log('An error has occurred');
                         // res.send(err);
                         result= finalData = err
                     } else {
                         if(!prayer){
                             // console.log(data2.id+'--0');
                             data2.prayersCount = 0;
                             result = deferred.resolve(finalData.push(data2))
                         } else {
                             // console.log(data2.id+'--'+prayer.length);
                             data2.prayersCount = prayer.length;
                             // console.log(prayer)
                             result =  deferred.resolve(finalData.push(data2))
                         } // else for data forward
                     }
                     deferred.promise;
                 })
                // deferred.resolve(finalData);

             })
             /*if(finalData.length > 0) { return finalData;}*/
        }
}
```

finalData is returned undefined.

Comment: its a promise. I can remove it, i was trying to solve the prob so i tried this thing

Comment: Your function `getPrayerInCat()` doesn't return anything or return anything to a callback. Also it would be helpful if you removed the comments from your code and updated your post to include what your excepted output should be. And should you be return `deferred.promise;`, instead of just showing it?

Comment: I think finalData is undefined because it's being access before it's populated from your deferred object.

Comment: @MuddassirKhanani: Afair, `Q` has no `moulde` method. What do you mean? Where did you use it in your code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's start with the general rule for using promises:

> **Every function that does something asynchronous must return a promise**

Which functions are these in your case? It's `getPrayerInCat`, the `forEach` callback, and `Prayer.find`.

Hm, `Prayer.find` doesn't return a promise, and it's a library function so we cannot modify it. Rule 2 comes into play:

> **[Create an immediate wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for every function that doesn't**

In our case that's easy with [Q's node-interfacing helpers](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnbindnodemethod-thisarg-args):

```
var find = Q.nbind(Prayer.find, Prayer);
```

Now we have only promises around, and do no more need any deferreds. Third rule comes into play:

> **Everything that does something with an async result goes into a `.then` callback**

…and returns the result. Hell, that result can even be a promise if "something" was asynchronous! With this, we can write the complete callback function:

```
function getPrayerCount(data2) {
    var id = data2.id;
    return find({prayerCat:id})
//  ^^^^^^ Rule 1
    .then(function(prayer) {
//  ^^^^^ Rule 3
        if (!prayer)
            data2.prayersCount = 0;
        else
            data2.prayersCount = prayer.length;
        return data2;
//      ^^^^^^ Rule 3b
    });
}
```

Now, we have something a bit more complicated: a loop. Repeatedly calling `getPrayerCount()` will get us multiple promises, whose asynchronous tasks run in parallel and resolve in unknown order. We want to wait for all of them - i.e. get a promise that resolves with all results when each of the tasks has finished.

For such complicated tasks, don't try to come up with your own solution:

> **Check the API of your library**

And there we find [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall), which does exactly this. Writing `getPrayerInCat` is a breeze now:

```
function getPrayerInCat(data) {
    var promises = data.map(getPrayerCount); // don't use forEach, we get something back
    return Q.all(promises);
//  ^^^^^^ Rule 1
}
```

If we needed to do anything with the array that `Q.all` resolves to, just apply Rule 3.

Comment: I have used your code but same issue it return form find and donot wait for resukt from db . So the final result is undefined.

Comment: getPrayerCat('').then(function(data){
        getPrayerInCat(data)
    }).then(function(data2){
         console.log(data2)
    })

var getPrayerInCat = function(data){
    var result ;
    var finalData = [];
    if(data.length >0){
        var promises = data.map(getPrayerCount); 
        return Q.all(promises);
        }
}

Comment: function getPrayerCount(data2) {
    var id = data2.id;
    return find({prayerCat:id})
        .then(function(prayer) {
            if (!prayer)
                data2.prayersCount = 0;
            else
                data2.prayersCount = prayer.length;
            return data2;
        });
}

Comment: You forgot about Rule 1 in your `then` callback. It needs to be `getPrayerCat('').then(function(data){` **`return`** `getPrayerInCat(data); }).then(…)`. Without returning anything, the promise resolves to `undefined`…

Comment: I again have same issue this time one more loop is added @Bergi

Comment: findAllGroup(query).then(function(data){
        return   getmemberInfo(data)
    }).then(function(data2){
          
            res.send(data2)
        })
var getmemberInfo = function(data){
    var result ;
    var finalData = [];
    if(data.length >0){
        var promises = data.map(memberCount); 
        return Q.all(promises);
    }
}

function memberCount(data2) {
    var members = (data2.members).split(",");;
    if(members.length >0){
        var promises2 = members.map(memberInfo); 
        return Q.all(promises2);

    }
}

Comment: function memberInfo(member){
    var id = member
    return   find({_id:member})
        .then(function(User) {
            if (!User){
                console.log(User)}
            else{
                console.log(User)}
            return member;
        });

}

Comment: var find = Q.nbind(User.findOne, User);

Comment: I can't spot a mistake right away. If you still have an issue with it, you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you can format your code readably.

Comment: This is a really great answer, I would suggest to add a rule 4 or an example on how to handle multiple promises in case library don't do that. A reader may be interest in this: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)