# Does this JavaScript function need to return a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred

Let's say I have some JS that makes an AJAX call like this:

```
$.getJSON(myUrl, { targetState: state }, function (jsonData) {
}).success(function (jsonData) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Now let's assume I want to wrap this code in a function and have it return some value, in the success block, so I can call it from various places in my app. Should the function I create return a Promise? I'm thinking it probably does, but I've never created a JS function that returned a Promise so I'm not entirely certain when I need to do this.

Comment: `$.getJSON` returns `jqXHR` object which implements the Promise interface. So you could just return result of `$.getJSON` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should the function I create return a Promise

Yes. If you want to use promises, *every* function that does anything asynchronous should return a promise for its result. No exceptions, really.

> wrap this code in a function and have it return some value in the success block

Good news: It's not complicated, as `$.getJSON` does already give you a promise to work with. Now all you need to do is to use the [`then` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) - you can pass a callback to do something with the result and get back a new promise for the return value of the callback. You'd just replace your `success` with `then`, and add some `return`s:

```
function target(state) {
    var myUrl = …;
    return $.getJSON(myUrl, { targetState: state })
//  ^^^^^^
    .then(function (jsonData) {
//   ^^^^
        /* Do something with jsonData */
        return …;
//      ^^^^^^
    });
}
```

With promises, you do no more pass a callback to the `$.getJSON` function any more.

> so I can call it from various places in my app

Now, you can call that `target` function, and get the result of the returned promise in another callback:

```
target({…}).then(function(result) {
    …; return …;
});
```

Comment: You might also be interested in [these general rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572) for working with promises.

Comment: It might be beneficial to give OP example usage of how the `target` function can be used from the outside by chaining `then` to it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: [X] Done

Comment: Well, I can't upvote twice :P I think it really helps to tell people how usage works though.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for doing this. I wish I could upvote this 10 times.