# Nested Promises Stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, protractor

The following code gets stuck:

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var testPromise = function(){
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){

    element.all(by.repeater('item in menu.items')).first().then(function(el){
        console.log('test f');
        fulfill(el);
        console.log('test fe');
    });

  });
};
```

... called by the following:

```
testPromise().then(function(el){
    console.log('test successful '+el);
});
```

The console prints

```
test f
test fe
```

And get stuck no more code is executed. It never reaches the then although fulfill has been called.

if using nested promises is an anti pattern then how do I do the following without a nested promise:

```
var getMenuItemEl = function(itemName){
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){

    var elFound;
    element.all(by.repeater('item in menu.items')).then(function(els){
        async.each(els, function(el, callback){
            el.getText().then(function(text){
                console.log('getMenuItemEl:'+text);
                if(text === itemName){
                    elFound = el;
                }
                callback(); 
            });
        }, function(err){
            console.log('complete '+elFound);
            if(elFound){
                console.log('fulfill');
                fulfill(elFound);
                console.log('after fulfill');
            }else{
                reject('no item found');
            }
        });

    });

  });
};
```

This also gets stuck after the fulfill has been called

Comment: Which `promise` library are you using?

Comment: Notice that you are using [an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) with that `new Promise` thing. Avoiding it might solve the issue, although your code should indeed work as it is.

Comment: i read it as "nested promises suck"

Comment: promise library is then/promise

Comment: it gets weirder if i take the first out then the code works

Comment: Uh, the [`then/promise`](https://github.com/then/promise) library does not seem to provide a `.first()` method??? What is it?

Comment: var first = element.all(by.css('.items li')).first();

Comment: But if `.all()` already returns a promise (or at least something with a `then` method?), then what does `.first()` on that *mean*?

Comment: This code is given as an example on the protractor website. I don't know what promise library protractor uses. The object returned by element.all() extends a promise.

Comment: I'm also confused by the protractor api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves my problem, mainly due to my lack of knowledge of the protractor api

```
var doClickMenuItemEl = function(itemName){
  return element.all(by.repeater('item in menu.items')).filter(function(elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === itemName;
    });
  }).then(function(els){
    els[0].click();
  });   
};
```

It also says on https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/379 that

> Yes, this is inherited from webdriver promises, which are not quite promise A+ compliant, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

> if using nested promises is an anti pattern then how do I do the following without a nested promise

You would not use the `async` library. Since all your methods (`element.all()`, `el.getText()` etc) do already return promises, you don't need to go back to node-style error callbacks. From [my "rules for promises"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572),
**every async function (even if it is a callback) should return a promise**, and **use your libraries' methods to compose them**. You really don't need to call the `Promise` constructor on your own. That iteration you are doing there can be easily done by a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the `els`, then collecting all the single promises together with [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/then/promise#promiseallarray).

```
function getMenuItemEl(itemName) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('item in menu.items'))
    .then(function(els){
        return Promise.all(els.map(function(el) {
            return el.getText()
            .then(function(text){
                console.log('getMenuItemEl:'+text);
                return (text === itemName) ? el : null;
            });
        }));
    })
    .then(function(foundEls) {
        for (var i=0; i<foundEls.length; i++)
            if (foundEls[i] != null) {
                console.log('fulfill');
                return foundEls[i];
            }
        throw new Error('no item found');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Doing this synchronously would be so simple.

Comment: The error is still there when i run this new code. It gets stuck after the last getMenuItemEl, it never reaches fulfill and no error is thrown

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe there's a bug in the API that you use, and it returns ever-pending promises? Although in your original script, where you call `fulfill` and then nothing happens, it rather looks like there is endless loop or so after the execution of that last callback. Can you maybe set up a minimal demo that reproduces the issue so that we can investigate?

Comment: I also dont understand how this is working. What hapens when you return foundEl[i], is this function returning a promise or an element?

Comment: The callback function from which I `return foundEl[i]` does return an element. The `.then(…)` to which this callback is passed returns a promise for this element, as it waits for `foundEls` before executing the callback.