# bluebird recursive promise not getting resolved/fulfilled

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Using BlueBird promises, I am trying to make `getCredentials` into a promise that will work as `getCredentials.then(function() { do this and that } );`. Not sure what I am doing wrong, because when I resolve in `writeToFile` the promise is not counted as resolved/fullfilled.

```
function getPassword(user) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    read({prompt: "Password: ", silent: true, replace: "*" }, function (er, pass) {
        rest.postJson(URL, payload(user, pass))
            .on('fail', httpFail)
            .on('error', conError)
            .on('success', writeToFile);
    });
    });
}

function getCredentials() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    read({prompt: "Username: "}, function (er, user) {
        getPassword(user);
    });
    });
}

function writeToFile(data, response) {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    tokenFile = 'gulp/util/token-file.json'
    token = {
        id: data.access.token.id,
        expires: data.access.token.expires
    }
    token = JSON.stringify(token);
    fs.writeFile(tokenFile, token, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Token was successfully retrieved and written to " .cyan +
            tokenFile .cyan + "." .cyan);
    resolve();
    });
     });
}

module.exports = getCredentials;
```

Comment: Why are you always ignoring `er`rors? Use proper [promisification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) instead of the `Promise` constructor.

Comment: What are `httpFail` and `conError`?

Comment: Those are call back functions. I tried using promisify but didn't have success...I thought was because maybe some of the functions didn't fall exactly to node standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure what I am doing wrong, because when I resolve in writeToFile the promise is not counted as resolved/fullfilled

Well, the promise that you did return from `writeToFile` *is* fulfilled.
But the promises that are returned from `getPassword` or `getCredentials` never are - you are not calling *their* `resolve` functions. The Promise constructor does not magically know about the asynchronous callbacks that were used inside of it, or that there <s>were</s> will be promises created in them.

You cannot `return` anything from an asynchronous callback, your only way to signal results from there is by calling another (callback) function. Inside of the `Promise` constructor's resolver, that would be the `resolve` and `reject` callbacks.

You might want to have a look a [my rules for promise development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572). We almost never use the `Promise` constructor, only to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) at the lowest possible level. In your case, that would be

```
function readAsync(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        read(options, function (err, pass) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(pass);
        }
    });
}
function postAsync(url, payload) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        rest.postJson(url, payload)
        .on('fail', reject)
        .on('error', reject)
        .on('success', resolve);
    });
}
```

though with Bluebird we can simplify the first to

```
var readAsync = Promise.promisify(read);
```

and similar use

```
var writeFileAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile, fs);
```

Now that we have those promise-returning functions, we can apply the rest of the rules and compose them together, without needing to use the `Promise` constructor any more:

```
function getPassword(user) {
    return readAsync({prompt: "Password: ", silent: true, replace: "*" })
    .then(function(pass) {
        return postAsync(URL, payload(user, pass))
    });
}

function getCredentials() {
    return readAsync({prompt: "Username: "}).then(getPassword);
}

function writeToFile(data, response) {
    var tokenFile = 'gulp/util/token-file.json';
    var token = JSON.stringify({
        id: data.access.token.id,
        expires: data.access.token.expires
    });
    return writeFileAsync(tokenFile, token).then(function() {
        console.log("Token was successfully retrieved and written to " .cyan +
                    tokenFile .cyan + "." .cyan);
    });
}

module.exports = getCredentials;
```

Comment: This example and explanation is an incredible learning resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`getCredentials()` and `getPassword()` are not resolving their promises when they are complete.  They never get resolved.

I assume from the code that you also want to chain the getPassword promise with the writeToFile promise so getPassword doesn't resolve until writeToFile does.

That could look something like this:

```
function getPassword(user) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        read({prompt: "Password: ", silent: true, replace: "*" }, function (er, pass) {
            rest.postJson(URL, payload(user, pass))
                .on('fail', httpFail)
                .on('error', conError)
                .on('success', function(data, response) {
                    writeToFile(data, response).then(resolve);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

You probably also want to implement error handling.

Comment: Please don't propose the <s>deferred</s>Promise constructor antipattern.

Comment: @Bergi - feel free to propose your own answer that works differently.