# sequentialize async function calls with WinJS.Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, winjs

I have a async function that should not execute another async request until the previous one has been finished.

```
pendingCatalogRequest = WinJS.Promise.as();
loadCatalogAsync = function(name) {
    var loadAsync = function() {
      return getXmlAsync("catalogdata/" + name);
    }
    return pendingCatalogRequest = pendingCatalogRequest.then(loadAsync, loadAsync);
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? Or am I missing something?

Will the `loadAsync` closure garbage collected when the `loadCatalogAsync` function is left?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way to handle this?

Yes, this seems fine.

> <s>Or am I missing something?</s>

<s>Consider what happens with rejections - they will block your whole queue. You might want to `.catch` them for the queuing promise.</s> See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284443/1048572) for a more complete example.

> Will the `loadAsync` closure garbage collected when the `loadCatalogAsync` function is left?

No, it will get garbage collected after is is run, until then the `pendingCatalogRequest.then` method still holds a reference to it.

Comment: > Consider what happens with rejections - they will block your whole queue. You might want to .catch them for the queuing promise.

Am I not catching them with the error handler?

> See here for a more complete example.

The example is not WinJS unfortunately.

Comment: Oops, I must have missed your error handler. The linked code should work when you swap jQuery's `$.when()` to `WinJS.Promise.as()`, the rest is implementation-independent.

Comment: Still fail to see what your code does different than mine? Can you explain please?

Comment: It won't store the latest xml result in the `pendingCatalogRequest`, which would always be a promise that is fulfilled with `undefined` only (in contrast to the promises returned from `loadCatalogAsync`)