# Bluebird: Waiting for one promise to settle

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

At the risk of sounding stupid: What's the most efficient way to wait for one promise to settle? Say I have promise A and I want to create promise B. The fulfillment of B does not depend on the final value of A. It should proceed even if A is rejected. The process shouldn't start, however, until A is settled one way or the other.

What I have currently looks like the following:

```
var prevResult;

function doStuff() {
    if (prevResult) {
        prevResult = promise.settle([ prevResult ]).then(function() {
            return doStuff();
        })
    } else {
        prevResult = updateDB().finally(function() {
            prevResult = null;
        });
    }
    return prevResult;
}
```

The code is a bit non-obvious. I'm also a bit worried about chaining a bunch of promises from settle() together, seeing how it's function for performing less trivial kind of coordination. Seems like there ought to be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: You mean you want to have two promises and even if Promise A is rejected, you ll ignore it and want to proceed?

Comment: @thefourtheye. Yes. The operations that generate A and B are independent. They just can't happen concurrently.

Comment: Yes, your code is very non-obvious, especially that `prevResult = null` thing. What exactly is this for? What is `doStuff`?

Comment: Setting `prevResult` to null allow the next operation to proceed. I guess the code would be a bit more obvious if I make the condition `prevResult && !prevResult.isFulfilled())` and remove the finally(). That'd mean the fulfillment value doesn't get gc'ed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, `.reflect` was introduced as a more flexible `.settle` and a better abstraction altogether. Your use case sounds like something that's easy to do with `.reflect`

```
A.reflect().then(function(){
   return doSomethingThatReturnsB();
});
```

A full example with your code:

```
var prevResult;
function doStuff() {
    prevResult = Promise.resolve(prevResult).reflect().then(function(){
        return updateDB();
    });
    return prevResult;
}
```

Comment: `.reflect` seems to have gained some momentum. I would find `.inspectify` more intuitive.

Comment: You know I <3 you dude but that's a terrible name :D

Comment: Trouble with "reflect" here is that it's figurative. Literally, reflection is what happens in a mirror, or as [modelled mathematically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection). The only way I'll ever remember Petkaantonov's usage is `"reflect" == "inspectify"` :D

Comment: Relaxation also means looking at oneself http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think the second example is correct though.

Comment: @cleong glad I could help, feel free to suggest an edit to the second example :)

Comment: I fixed your example, I think.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, reflect also has a precedent in computer science https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **finally**, which fires regardless of the outcome of the previous promise.

Following code is from the bluebird github doco.

```
function ajaxGetAsync(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.addEventListener("error", reject);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", resolve);
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.send(null);
    }).finally(function() {
        $("#ajax-loader-animation").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: finally() returns a promise that yields the value of the promise on which it's called (and not the return value of the callback).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two promise-returning functions `doAsync_A` and `doAsync_B`.

The following expression will execute `doAsync_A`, wait for its promise to settle (to become fulfilled or rejected), then execute `doAsync_B`

```
Promise.settle([doAsync_A()]).then(doAsync_B);
```

`doAsync_B` will be passed a "PromiseInspection" array (here a single element). If necessary, you can test whether `doAsync_A` was successful or failed.

```
function doAsync_B(results) {
    var r = results[0];
    if (r.isFulfilled()) {  // check if was successful
        console.log(r.value()); // the promise's return value
    } else if (r.isRejected()) { // check if the read failed
        console.log(r.reason()); // the promise's rejection reason
    }
}
```

*adapted from the [bluebird documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#settle---promise)*

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to put `doStuff` as both fulfillment and rejection handler:

```
prevResult = prevResult.then(function() { return doStuff(); },
                             function() { return doStuff(); });
```

Or alternatively

```
prevResult = prevResult.catch(ignore).then(function() { return doStuff(); });
```

---

It seems you are trying to queue `updateDB` operations. I would recommend not to reset `prevResult` to `null`, but instead just make it a promise that is fulfilled when all queued operations are done. Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284443/1048572).

Comment: Why the anonymous wrappers?  Why not just `.then(doStuff, doStuff)`?

Comment: @jfriend00: Depends on whether you want any arguments to `doStuff` or not. If you don't care, then `.then(doStuff, doStuff)` is certainly better.