# Map Promise.all output with promises index

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am using nodejs v8+ which supports default async await style of code.

In my problem, I am trying to push all the promises into an array and then use Promise.all to with await keyword to get the responses. But the problem is, I am not able to map the promises with the keys.

Here is the example:

```
let users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];

    let promises = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      let response = this.myApiHelper.getUsersData(users[i]);
      promises.push(response);
    }
    let allResponses = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Here I get all the collected response of all the responses, but I actually want to map this by user. 
For example currently I am getting data in this format:

```
[
{
  user1 Data from promise 1
},
{
  user2 Data from promise 2
},
{
  user3 Data from promise 3
}
]
```

But I want data in this format:

```
[
 {
  "user1": Data from promise 1
 },
 {
   "user2": Data from promise 2
 },
 {
   "user3": Data from promise 3
 }
]
```

I am sure there must be a way to map every promise by user, but I am not aware of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are going to create an array of user. Iterate over it to create an array of `Promise` we give to `Promise.all`. Then iterate on the answer to create an object that's matching the user with the associated answer from `getUsersData`.

Something to know about `Promise.all` is that the order of the returned data depends on the order of the `promises` given in entry of it.

```
const users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'];

const rets = await Promise.all(users.map(x => this.myApiHelper.getUsersData(x)));

const retWithUser = rets.map((x, xi) => ({
   user: users[xi],
   ret: x,
}));
```

[Here](https://ariya.io/2013/01/es6-and-array-comprehension) you have a great tutorial about Array methods `(map, filter, some...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer accepted by me is one of the solution, which I think is perfect and I will keep as accepted answer but I would like to post my solution which I figured out later which is much simpler:

We could simply use this:

```
let finalData = {};
let users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
await Promise.all(users.map(async(eachUser) => {
    finalData[user] = await this.myApiHelper.getUsersData(eachUser);
}))
console.log(finalData);
```

Answer (score -1):

as described here
[How to use Promise.all with an object as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292921/how-to-use-promise-all-with-an-object-as-input)

Here is a simple ES2015 function that takes an object with properties that might be promises and returns a promise of that object with resolved properties.

```
function promisedProperties(object) {

  let promisedProperties = [];
  const objectKeys = Object.keys(object);

  objectKeys.forEach((key) => promisedProperties.push(object[key]));

  return Promise.all(promisedProperties)
    .then((resolvedValues) => {
      return resolvedValues.reduce((resolvedObject, property, index) => {
        resolvedObject[objectKeys[index]] = property;
        return resolvedObject;
      }, object);
    });

}
```

And then you will use it like so:

```
var promisesObject = {};
users.map((element, index) => object[element] = this.myApiHelper.getUsersData(users[index]));
promisedProperties(object).then(response => console.log(response));
```

Note that first of all you need an object with key/promise.

Comment: Though I have not downvoted and it seems a feasible solution but at the same time its kind of complex. So accepted a simple solution