# How to convert nested setTimeouts to promises

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

Using rsvp.js or any other promises/A+ implementation how can I turn code like...

```
console.log('step 1');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('step 2');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('step 3');
  }, 100);
}, 300);
```

into a promises implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a delay function which returns a Promise and it actually resolves it after the specified time elapses in `setTimeout`, like this

```
function delay(time) {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}
```

and then you can invoke it like this

```
console.log("step 1");
delay(3000)
    .then(function () {
        console.log("step 2");
        return delay(1000);
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log("step 3");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain the promises:

```
// Set up the functions which contain the promises
function step1() {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve();
    });
}

function step2() {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        }, 300);
    });
}

function step3() {  
    return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    });
}

// Now execute them:
step1()
    .then(step2)
    .then(step3)
```

You can read more here: http://www.toptal.com/javascript/javascript-promises

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with using [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), there's a very simple solution baked into the library:

```
console.log('step 1');
Q.delay(300).then(function() {
    console.log('step 2');
    return Q.delay(200);
}).then(function() {
    console.log('step 3');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [rules of thumb for promise development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572)! First of all, we need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the  `setTimeout` calls, so that we get a function which returns us a promise for it. With [the RSVP `Promise` constructor](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#basic-usage), it would look like this:

```
function delay(time) {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}
```

Now, we can [chain](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#chaining) the log statements using `then` instead of passing the callback right into `setTimeout`:

```
console.log("step 1");
delay(3000).then(function() {
    console.log("step 2");
    return delay(1000).then(function() {
        console.log("step 3");
    });
});
```

…and do get back a promise for when all three steps are executed.

However, the actual feature of `then` is that you can [unnest the callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) now, and get exactly the same result back. So your chain would look like this:

```
console.log("step 1");
delay(3000).then(function() {
    console.log("step 2");
    return delay(1000);
}).then(function() {
    console.log("step 3");
});
```