# Bluebird promise spread method returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js, bluebird

I don't know if I'm not using the `.spread` method correctly while working with **Bluebird** promises on **Sails.js** models. Here's what I have:

```
transactionAsync('BEGIN')
.then(function() {
    return Model.findOne({ id: 5) });
})
.then(function(results){
    if(!results) {
        return res.notFound();
    }
    crypto.randomBytes(24, function(err, buf) {
        if(err) throw new Error(err);
        var token =  buf.toString('hex');
        // This is where it fails
        return [results, token];
    });
})
.spread(function(results, token) {
    // It doesn't get to log these
    console.log(results, token);
    ...
})
...
```

After returning `[results, token]` on the second `.then` (inside of the crypto callback), it spits out

```
[TypeError: expecting an array, a promise or a thenable]
```

I removed the rest of the code after `.spread`, since it's not really relevant, and that's where execution stops before returning an error.

**I just want to pass variables `results` and `token` to the function inside of `.spread`. What am I doing wrong?**

Any help is great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your execution stops at .spread()?

Comment: Yeah, well, it doesn't get to execute the code inside of `.spread()`, and I'm sure that whatever is inside of crypto actually runs, before the return. I'm guessing maybe I shouldn't be placing async code like crypto.randomBytes inside of a promise? Or perhaps just make crypto.randomBytes a part of the promise chain.

Comment: Just put some console.log() and trace where your execution stops? Here your error is indicating that either any of the then() function or spread() is not getting expected arguments so may be some where your flow is returning as a undefined.

Comment: That's what I did. Placing `console.log("bla")` before `return [results, token] ` results in `bla` being logged. But nothing logs after that.

Answer (score 2):

> After returning `[results, token]` on the second `.then`

That's not what you're doing. You're returning inside of the crypto callback, where it is meaningless. Neither does anybody know of this callback, nor do you actually `return` anything from the *`then` callback*.

The [first rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572) of promise development is to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the underlying API so that you can work on pure promises.

```
var crypto = Promise.promisifyAll(crypto);
// or specifically:
var randomBytes = Promise.promisify(crypto.randomBytes);
```

Now we can follow rule 3b and actually return a (promise) result from then `then` callback:

```
…
.then(function(results) {
    if (!results) {
        return res.notFound();
    }
    return crypto.randomBytesAsync(24) // returns a promise now!
//  ^^^^^^
    .then(function(buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        return [results, token];
    });
})
.spread(function(results, token) {
    console.log(results, token);
    …
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.then(function(results){
    if(!results) {
        return res.notFound();
    }
    crypto.randomBytes(24, function(err, buf) {
        if(err) throw new Error(err);
        var token =  buf.toString('hex');
        // This is where it fails
        return [results, token];
    });
})
```

is wrong. You are `return` int from inside the `randomBytes` callback, not inside the `then`, so your `then` simply returns `undefined` and you then try to `.spread` that. In order to properly wait for `randomBytes`, you need to create a promise for that value.

```
.then(function(results){
    if(!results) {
        return res.notFound();
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        crypto.randomBytes(24, function(err, buf) {
            if(err) return reject(new Error(err));
            var token =  buf.toString('hex');
            // This is where it fails
            resolve([results, token]);
        });
    });
})
```