# How to use Promises in RactiveJS?

Tags: promise, ractivejs

Although there is an [example in Ractive docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/promises), I am a starter with promises and I don't understand the mentioned example:

```
var Promise = Ractive.Promise;

var p = new Promise( function ( fulfil, reject ) {
  doSomethingAsync( function ( error, result ) {
    if ( error ) {
      return reject( error );
    }

    fulfil( result );
  });
});
```

How can I use Ractive's implementation to run some functions asynchronously?

Edit: An use case example is when I have, in the same function, *synchronous* and *asynchronous* operations and I need to return a Promise when all of these operations where processed.

Comment: Please ask a more specific function. What "some functions" do you want/need to implement? What problems did you meet? Show us your attempt. If this is a question about understanding, please put the respective example in your question (there are multiple ones on the linked page!), and explain minutely what you understand and what not.

Comment: Thanks. Provided the mentioned example and a use case

Comment: Maybe you'll want to start with [these rules of thumb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572) (more a design question rather than explaining the `Promise` constructor). Usually you don't combine synchronous with asynchronous functions. You have functions returning promises (async), and then chain them. Can you please give a concrete example of which functions you have and want to use? Maybe a code snippet in callback style (no promises yet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a question about promises than about Ractive, so [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) would be worth a read, though it's a bit heavy.

Basically though, if you want to wait until several operations have finished, use `Promise.all`:

```js
var ready = Promise.all([
  getJSON( '/data.json' ), // async (returns a promise)
  domReady(),              // async
  reticulateSplines()      // sync
]);
```

`getJSON` and `domReady` will be executed simultaneously. So will `reticulateSplines`, not that it matters since it's synchronous. The value of `ready` is now a promise that will fulfil with an array containing the results of those three operations:

```js
ready.then( function ( values ) {
  var data     = values[0];
  var document = values[1];
  var splines  = values[2];
  // some code happens
}).catch( function ( err ) {
  // if something went wrong with any of those three
  // functions (e.g. couldn't find data.json), we'll
  // end up here
});
```

If you're transpiling your code with something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/), you can also use destructuring:

```js
ready.then( ([ data, document, splines ]) => {
  // some code happens
}).catch( err => {
  // handle error
});
```

Another useful function if you're dealing with maybe-sync-maybe-async stuff (though it really is better to avoid that sort of thing) is `Promise.resolve`:

```js
function crazyTown () {
  if ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {
    return 'sync!';
  } else {
    return new Promise( function ( fulfil, reject ) {
      setTimeout( function () {
        fulfil( 'async!' );
      }, 500 );
    });
  }
}

Promise.resolve( crazyTown() ).then( function ( type ) {
  console.log( type );
});
```

If your browser supports promises natively, Ractive will use those (i.e. `Ractive.Promise === window.Promise`) - if not, it uses its own spec-compliant implementation.