# Node return BluebirdJS Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I have a small problem, this script works perfectly, with one problem, the "runTenant" method is not returning a promise (that needs resolving from "all()".

This code:

```
Promise.resolve(runTenant(latest)).then(function() {
  end();
});
```

Calls this code:

```
function runTenant(cb) {
  return new Promise(function() {
    //global var
    if (!Tenant) {
      loadCoreModels();
      Tenant = bookshelf.core.bs.model('Tenant');
    }

    new Tenant().fetchAll()
      .then(function(tenants) {

        if (tenants.models.length == 0) {
          return;
        } else {
          async.eachSeries(tenants.models, function(tenant, next) {

            var account = tenant.attributes;
            Promise.resolve(db_tenant.config(account)).then(function(knex_tenant_config) {
              if (knex_tenant_config) {
                db_tenant.invalidateRequireCacheForFile('knex');
                var knex_tenant = require('knex')(knex_tenant_config);
                var knex_pending = cb(knex_tenant);
                Promise.resolve(knex_pending).then(function() {
                  next(null, null);
                });
              } else {
                next(null, null);
              }
            });

          });
        };
      });
  });
}
```

The code from runTenant is working correctly however it stalls and does not proceed to "end()" because the promise from "runTenant(latest)" isn't being resolved.

As if it weren't apparent, I am horrible at promises.  Still working on getting my head around them.

Many thanks for any help/direction!

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `Promise` constructor at all here (and basically, not anywhere else either), even if you made it work it would be an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). You've never resolved that promise - notice that the [`resolve` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters) to the `Promise` constructor callback is a very different function than [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

And you should not use the `async` library if you have a powerful promise library like Bluebird at hand.

> As if it weren't apparent, I am horrible at promises.

Maybe you'll want to have a look at my [rules of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572) for writing promise functions.

Here's what your function should look like:

```
function runTenant(cb) {
  //global var
  if (!Tenant) {
    loadCoreModels();
    Tenant = bookshelf.core.bs.model('Tenant');
  }
  return new Tenant().fetchAll().then(function(tenants) {
    // if (tenants.models.length == 0) {
    //  return;
    // } else
    // In case there are no models, the loop iterates zero times, which makes no difference
    return Promise.each(tenants.models, function(tenant) {
      var account = tenant.attributes;
      return db_tenant.config(account).then(function(knex_tenant_config) {
        if (knex_tenant_config) {
          db_tenant.invalidateRequireCacheForFile('knex');
          var knex_tenant = require('knex')(knex_tenant_config);
          return cb(knex_tenant); // can return a promise
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, that worked perfectly.  I'll read through your rules of thumb as well, as I would like to understand more clearly... as to what is exactly is happening.  I was under the impression that the first code calling the runTenant since it was in a Resolve method, that any promise returned to it would be resolved, the primary thing I notice with your suggestion (which worked perfectly) is that you resolved all promises before the return.  ben above, also recommended this.  Thank you both!

Comment: Ah, yeah, forgot to include a remark about your confusion with `resolve`. Feel free to comment about every part you don't understand, I'll clarify those.

Comment: I'm not even sure whether you need that `Promise.resolve(db_tenant.config(account))` - what does `config(…)` return?

Comment: config returns a promise as well

Comment: I see, in that case you can savely omit the `Promise.resolve` call

Answer (score 0):

You need to return all the nested promises. I can't run this code, so this isn't a drop it fix. But hopefully, it helps you understand what is missing.

```
function runTenant(cb) {
    //global var
    if (!Tenant) {
        loadCoreModels();
        Tenant = bookshelf.core.bs.model('Tenant');
    }

    return new Tenant().fetchAll() //added return
        .then(function (tenants) {

            if (tenants.models.length == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                var promises = []; //got to collect the promises
                tenants.models.each(function (tenant, next) {

                    var account = tenant.attributes;
                    var promise = Promise.resolve(db_tenant.config(account)).then(function (knex_tenant_config) {
                        if (knex_tenant_config) {
                            db_tenant.invalidateRequireCacheForFile('knex');
                            var knex_tenant = require('knex')(knex_tenant_config);
                            var knex_pending = cb(knex_tenant);
                            return knex_pending; //return value that you want the whole chain to resolve to
                        }
                    });
                    promises.push(promise); //add promise to collection
                });
                return Promise.all(promises); //make promise from all promises
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using built-in Promises. I highly recommend you use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) instead. It has built in method like Promise.each() that would make this easier. It also has a helpful warning system that would have warned you about some of the errors here.

Answer (score 0):

Your promise in `runTenant` function is never resolved. You must call `resolve` or `reject` function to resolve promise:

```
function runTenant() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // somewhere in your code
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
});
```

And you shouldn't pass `cb` in `runTenant` function, use promises chain:

```
runTenant()
 .then(latest)
 .then(end)
 .catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
 });
```