# Putting Togther Q Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm learning about JS promises and have made some progress in my understanding of things, however unsure how to bring it together with `return` and using `Q.all`

So say I have a function: (`getParentsForLocation` returns a promise)

```
    function doBusiness() {

    return Q.all(
    locations.map(function(item, currentIndex) {
         return getParentsForLocation(item.id)
        .then(function(res) {
             return checkParent(res, currentIndex)
          }

        });
    }))
    .then(_.uniq(locations))
  }
```

Then following this i.e. after that map has gone through all elements in the `locations` array, I want to run something like underscore's `uniq` function: `_.uniq(someArrayIHave);`

1. Do i need to place this in a `Q.all([])`? \
2. If so, would it run each method in that array sequentially?
3. I presume there is something I'd need to do with that `doBusiness()` function, e.g. return some promise, but unsure how that would look?

Any help appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: So you want to wait for all the created promises, and then somewhere else (i.e. not in `doBusiness(...)` function), you want to call `_.uniq(...)` on some other array, do you confirm?

Comment: There is one array, I want ``doBusiness`` to work on that, then once its completed I want to call ``_.uniq``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to place this in a `Q.all(…)`?

Yes. Your `map()` call should get you an array of promises.

> If so, would it run each method in that array sequentially?

No. Or at least, we don't know, they could do anything on the inside.

> I presume there is something I'd need to do with that `doBusiness()` function, e.g. return some promise

Yes. From my [promise rules of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572): *If a function does something asynchronous, it must return a promise.* This is also true for your two callback functions.

> How would that look?

```
function doBusiness() {
    return Q.all(locations.map(function(item, currentIndex) {
//  ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
        return getParentsForLocation(item.id)
//      ^^^^^^
        .then(function(res) {
            return updateDB(res, currentIndex);
//          ^^^^^^
        });
    }));
//    ^
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense - but where would I call ``_.uniq(myArray)`` - as ``myArray`` would be only be ready for that once ``doBusiness`` has completed?

Comment: Just place `.then(_.uniq)` after the promise that `Q.all()` got you, it will return another promise for the duplicate-free array

Comment: I've updated my question with my full code above with your suggestions - does that look correct?

Comment: Nah, you need either `.then(function(locations) { return _.uniq(locations); })` or `.then(_.uniq)`; always pass a function to `then`. And your callback doesn't return anything (i.e. `undefined`) if `res` is empty, not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Ok, and finally to actually kickstart it all - do i need to place in a line of code like ``Q([doBusiness()])``  - because when i do i get ``state: pending``

Comment: No, you need to do `doBusiness().then(function(result) { console.log(result) }, console.error);`

Comment: Awesome - got it now - so the key take away point - need to actually ``return`` promises

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134993/discussion-between-usermod2-and-bergi).