# Writing mocha test for nested Promise calls

Tags: javascript, promise

I have nested promise calls structure as follow:

```
validateUser()
.then(() => {
  getUserInformation()
  .then((userInformation) => {
    Promise.all([
        getUserDebitAccounts(userInformation), 
        getUserCreditAccounts(userInformation)
    ])
    .then(([drAcc, crAcc]) => {
        //do something
    })
  })
})
.catch(error => {
  callback(error);
});
```

First of all is there a way to simplify these nested calls? As you can see they are structure as per dependency. So this is a most logical way I came up.

Second can I use `catch` at end to catch all the rejects on all above call. Do I have to add separate `catch` for each calls?

Third I want to write a mocha test what level of Promise mocking I have to do for these methods some outline will be helpful.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can flatten out your promise chain by returning the promise, see here: http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [you can and should flatten your chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572). To do that you'll need to [`return` the inner promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) from the `then` callbacks, which you will need anyway to make the single `catch` in the end work.

```
return validateUser()
.then(getUserInformation)
.then(userInformation =>
  Promise.all([
    getUserDebitAccounts(userInformation), 
    getUserCreditAccounts(userInformation)
  ])
).then(([drAcc, crAcc]) => {
  // do something
  return …;
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: seems like we can combine first two calls in `.all` as they are independent. So just wanna check if `Promise.all([validateUser(), getUserInformation()]).then(([, userInformation]) => {...}).then(..).catch(..)` will be right way to put calls too.

Comment: Yes, you can do that *if* they are independent. However it looks like you would want to validate a user *before* getting any information about them. (Though if that was the case, I'd recommend not relying on side effects but explicitly passing a `validatedUser` object between them)

Comment: Do we need to add return on first two `then` calls -

Comment: @αƞjiβ Yes, you should [always `return`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572). In the arrow function shorthand, it's implicit.