# Promise.all does not wait till .then()

Tags: asynchronous, promise

I have problem with using Promise.all. If I understand correctly - *someArrayUpdate1* resolve few promises to an array (*someArray1*) asynchronously - so when Promise.all(someArray1) hit, sooner or latter it has all data. And the same thing happen with someArrayUpdate2 - so it start **immediately** building it's data (someArray2).

I thought that .then() will work like a brake so Promise.all(someArray2) will start to build it promises array **AFTER** Promise.all(someArray1) and thanks to that *TEST1 (mainArray)* object status will be turn ON.

Now the problem is that TEST1 (mainArray) object status is OFF. And I don't know how to change that. Any ideas?

```
<doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img2.jpg" />
<img src="img3.jpg" />

<script>

    // ARRAYS and FUNCTIONS:
    var mainArray = [{
        TEST1 : {
            status : ''
        },
        TEST2 : {
            status : ''
        },
        TEST3 : {
            status : ''
        }
    }];

    var someArray1 = []; // for imgs
    var someArray2 = []; // for objects

    function someArray1Update(imgSrc, imgCounter) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {// - for marking asynchronous data flow

                    // this is where the problem is (lets assume that this code must be placed here) - we update second array here for Promise.all(someArray2) but nothing happen... status is OFF
                    someArray2.push(someArray2Update('TEST1', 'on'));

                    return resolve({counter : imgCounter, url : imgSrc});
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    function someArray2Update(object, status) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return resolve({
                [object] : {
                    status : status,
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // CODE:
    someArray2.push(someArray2Update('TEST2', 'on')); // working fine

    var imgs = document.images || document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var imgsLength = imgs.length;
    var imgSrc = '';
    var imgsInfo = '';

    if (imgsLength !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < imgsLength; i++) {
            imgSrc = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');

            var imgCounter = i + 1;

            someArray1.push(someArray1Update(imgSrc, imgCounter));

            console.log('Image ' + [i + 1] + ' - ' +  imgSrc);
            imgsInfo  += 'Image ' + [i + 1] + ' - ' +  imgSrc + '<br />';
        }
    }
    else;

    someArray2.push(someArray2Update('TEST3', 'on')); // working fine

    Promise.all(someArray1).then(function(all) {
        console.log('\n');
        all.forEach(function(i) {
            console.log('someArray1 - ok');
        });
        console.log('\n');
    }).then(Promise.all(someArray2).then(function(array) {
            array.forEach(function(i) {
                mainArray[0] = Object.assign(mainArray[0], i);
            });
            console.log('\n=========================================================');
            console.log(mainArray);
            console.log('=========================================================\n');
        }));

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must pass a callback function to `then`, not the result of `Promise.all(someArray2).then(…)`

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how it should looks like (in asynchronous way with many someArray2Update functions in the code. Could you bring an example somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: You already did fine with `.then(function(all) { … })`.

Comment: ohhh got it... it was a code mistake, thanks for pointing it out @Bergi.

Answer (score 1):

```
).then(Promise.all(someArray2).then(function(array) {
            array.forEach(function(i) {
                mainArray[0] = Object.assign(mainArray[0], i);
            });
            console.log('\n=========================================================');
            console.log(mainArray);
            console.log('=========================================================\n');
        }));
```

this should looks like:

```
).then(*function()*{Promise.all(someArray2).then(function(array) {
            array.forEach(function(i) {
                mainArray[0] = Object.assign(mainArray[0], i);
            });
            }console.log('\n=========================================================');
            console.log(mainArray);
            console.log('=========================================================\n');
        }));
```

Thanks goes to @Bergi for pointing that out.

Comment: You'll also want to [`return` the promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572) from the callback so that you can [further chain on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).