# Chaining promises including fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have a React form with a file as an input, and the `onFileChange` saves `setFile(e.target.files[0])` (and also toggle a boolean `change`). Then when I submit the form:

- I first want to upload this file in the cloud (Cloudinary here),
- wait for the response object (namely the `url` and `public_id` I'm looking for)
- then I add this object (`url` and `'public_id`) to the formdata to post to the database backend.

I thought that chaining promises should do the job, but I can't achieve it.

Inside my `onFormSubmit`, I first define a promise that captures the none async data:

```
function init(fd){
  fd.append('input1'...)
  return Promise.resolve(fd)
}
```

so I can reuse the formdata to feed the next promise `upLoadToCL` that should 'normally' asynchronously append the response object from the cloud to the formdata, with:

`init(new FormData).then(res => upLoadToCL(res)).then(res=> ...)`

```
function upLoadToCL(fd) {
      if (changed) {
        // send 'file' (saved as state variable after input) to the cloud
        const newfd = new FormData();
        newfd.append("file", file);
        newfd.append("upload_preset", "ml_default");
        fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: newfd,
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          // append the formdata argument 'fd' with the result
          .then((res) => {
            setPhoto(res);
            fd.append("event[directCLUrl]", res.url);
            fd.append("event[publicID]", res.public_id);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw new Error(err);
          });
        return Promise.resolve(fd);
      }
    }
```

I checked that the first promise works and sends to the second promise a 'prefilled' formdata. Then the post request works, and returns a response as I can see that the state variable `photo` is updated some time in the futur. However, the promise itself returns a void formdata, even without chaining:

```
upLoadToCL(new FormData())
  .then(res=> {
    for (let [k,v] of res){
      console.log(k,v)
    }
  })
```

returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already doing the promise chaining fine. You just need to return the result of that promise chain instead of the `Promise.resolve(fd)` from your function:

```
function upLoadToCL(fd) {
  if (changed) {
    // send 'file' (saved as state variable after input) to the cloud
    const newfd = new FormData();
    newfd.append("file", file);
    newfd.append("upload_preset", "ml_default");
    return fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`, {
//  ^^^^^^
      method: "POST",
      body: newfd,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setPhoto(res);
      // append the formdata argument 'fd' with the result
      fd.append("event[directCLUrl]", res.url);
      fd.append("event[publicID]", res.public_id);
      return fd;
//    ^^^^^^ fulfilling the promise with the updated fd
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(fd);
//  ^^^^^^ always returning a promise for fd from uploadToCL()
  }
}
```

Comment: literally wrote the same thing, and then you commented :)
@NevD - my rule is to always remember to return a value when using promises or async/await.

Comment: @NickHolden Indeed, [that's the first rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572) :-)

Comment: this works beautifully! Thks, and thks for the link