# Is this proper use of JavaScript new Promise()?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Having recently "graduated" to using Promises, I worked up this pattern that absolutely does work, but I'm wondering if it is "technically" correct, or "best practices"?  `GetAsync()` is a function that makes a `fetch()` call to an API endpoint and receives back a JSON response.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    GetAsync("../api/CurrentUserAccount", resolve, reject, "json")
})
    .then((result) => {
        // code that does stuff with the user account json
    });
```

Again, this works just fine, but doing it this way, I am never doing anything with either `resolve` or `reject`.  That makes me think "*I'm doing this wrong*."  Is there a better, or more proper way to do this?

Comment: Please show the contents of the `GetAsync` function.

Comment: That would only depend on whether the `GetAsync` really expects the res/rej pair of the promise function. Which would be rather uncommon, in my opinion.

Comment: *"...makes an xmlHttpRequest()"* any reason that you're not using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)?

Comment: For best practices, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572). In particular, you should be calling the `new Promise` *inside* of `GetAsync` and make it `return` the promise.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for pointing that out.  I am actually using fetch().  Sorry.  Updated question.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks.  That's kinda what I figured I was doing wrong.

Comment: @KWallace If you're actually using `fetch` inside of `GetAsync`, then this definitely goes against best practices, in particular it's the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).

Comment: @Bergi.  Got it.  Will adjust accordingly.