# Promise encapsulating an unknown number of asynchronous work (ie. other promises)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to do n units of work, specifically I need to send an array of unkown size over a connection with an upper bound for the packet size. The packet sending routine runs asynchronously (inside a Node library) so I want to use promises. I have abstracted away everything and arrived at the following solution:

```
function worker(k, n, final_resolve, final_reject){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  {
    console.log("worker("+k+") start");
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() < 0.2)
        reject("error");
      else {
        console.log("worker("+k+") done");
        if (k < n) 
            resolve(worker(k + 1, n, final_resolve, final_reject).catch(final_reject));
        else 
            final_resolve("final");
      }
    }, 200);
  });
}

function asyncwork(n) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    worker(0, n, resolve, reject);
  }); 
};

const aw = asyncwork(5);
aw.then(
  (s) => { console.log("resolved " + s); return "resolved" + s; } ) // is this final "return" good for anything?
.catch(
    (e) => console.log("Error"));
```

How bad/stupid/risky is this? It seems to work but it is my first week in JavaScript and on more than one occasion code blew up in my face under changed conditions. I'm still a bit lost on the breadth of new topics and techniques. Feel free to critizise everything.

I'm sure there is some common method dealing with that kind of problem, or a library.

Comment: you say there's an "array of unknown size" - yet in your code, you call `asyncwork(5)` ... 5 is not "unknown"

Comment: Perhaps [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) / [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)? Also, consider using `async`/`await` wherever you can, it will make the code much easier to follow.

Comment: Have you considered using streams for this?  It sounds like what you're looking for actually fits well into the existing streams architecture.

Comment: @CherryDT I wanted to learn the principle behind it. Also, await would mean that the main thread would wait there until resolution/rejection, no? How would I split this off into a non-blocking method?

Comment: @CherryDT No, `Promise.all` won't help here, since the work is sequential

Comment: `await` is physically non-blocking, i.e. yielding to the event loop and other operations can run (but logically, from the point of view of your async function, it's "blocking", i.e. the next line in your function will execute only once the promise was resolved). The function will wait but the main thread will meanwhile do other things and get back to resuming your function when things are ready.

Comment: @JaromandaX I see that your sour comment has a reason. I will adapt the question accordingly.

Comment: sour comment? It was an observation. Any flavour associated is inferred not implied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How bad/stupid/risky is this? It seems to work but blew up on more than one occasion.

Passing down `resolve`, `reject`, `final_resolve`, `final_reject` - this is no good. This is callback-based code at best, and [calling `worker()` which returns itself a promise from inside a `new Promise` is an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! You tried to handle errors, but missed a few edge cases which will either hang or crash your program.

> I'm still a bit lost on the breadth of new topics and techniques.

Take a look at my [rules of thumb for promise development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756564/1048572). In particular, promisify at the lowest level, which is the `setTimeout` function that may fail:

```
function doWork(k) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`worker(${k}) start`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`worker(${k}) done`);
      if (Math.random() < 0.2)
        reject("error");
      else
        resolve();
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

(This is a placeholder for *one single asynchronous call* to the library you want to use).

Now from here on, use only promise combining and chaining. Using your recursive approach:

```
function runWorkers(n) {
  if (n <= 0) return Promise.resolve("final");
  return runWorkers(n-1).then(() => doWork(n));
}
```

or

```
function runWorkers(n) {
  function recurse(k) {
    if (k < n) return doWork(k).then(() => recurse(k + 1));
    else return Promise.resolve("final");
  }
  return recurse(0);
}
```

However, it's much easier to write this with `async`/`await` syntax and a simple loop:

```
async function runWorkers(n) {
  for (let k=0; k < n; k++) {
    await doWork(k);
  }
  return "final";
}
```

> is this final "return" good for anything?

Not really, if this part is the entrypoint of your program, i.e. the promise chain ends there and nothing else comes after it. Also, in that case you might want to [use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
runWorkers(5).then(
  (s) => { console.log("fulfilled:", s); },
  (e) => { console.error("Error:", e); }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I am still somewhat unsatisfied. The direct (without async) solution stacks all promise producers at once. Of course it was my fault to be so unspecific in my example, but what if the continuation of the worker chain depends on the result of the current worker?

Comment: @Vroomfondel The second approach with `recurse` (which is closer to your original code) can use the result of the first worker in the subsequent calls. And with the loop that's even easier.